# Connecting to device which requires specific IP

Tags: ip, ipv4, tcp

[Disclaimer: I'm a complete networking novice, and this question might not even be well suited for this site.  I welcome pointers to other stack exchanges if appropriate.]

I'm trying to connect a device (a laser, to be specific) to a PC via ethernet, with the eventual goal of connecting to it via a remote desktop program while I'm working from home.  The laser's manual describes how to do this, and it involves setting the PC's ethernet connection to have a fixed IPv4 address.  This prevents the PC from connecting to the internet, though, which defeats the purpose for me.

My main question is:

> **What might be some workarounds to this issue?**

If someone could explain why the PC's ethernet address needs to be set to a specific value for the laser to talk to it, that would be helpful too.  I'm happy to provide more details on my setup as needed, but I'm not sure which details are relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: I suspect that manual shows the device connected to a dedicated interface.

Answer (score 2):

Preferably, you configure the laser to use an address that fits your network. If that isn't possible to configure directly, it should be via DHCP - check the device's manual. If the address (and even more importantly the default gateway) cannot be configured, the devices TCP/IP implementation can be considered broken.

As a workaround: Most PC operating systems support configuring multiple IPv4 addresses for a NIC. That way, you can use the usual address compatible with your network and an additional network address for the communication with the laser which you simply attach to your network. Note that the PC's configuration is not within NESE's scope and off-topic here.

If you don't want to connect the laser to your network directly you can use a second, dedicated NIC in the PC with the required address. Depending on the actual requirements, a simple USB adapter might suffice.